# Fourier series for $f(x) = \cos(3x)$

Tags: fourier-series

I tried to to fourier series for $f(x) = \cos(3x)$, and I keep getting $0$ for all coeficients, $a_0$ and $a_n$. Am I missing something? Could $\cos(3x)$ be fourier series on its own?

Comment: I don't get it. This is like asking for Taylor series of $x^3$. A Fourier series is a sum of sines and cosines with integer multiples of some fundamental frequency. Can you show your work?

Comment: I found this question in old russian book. Precise question goes: Find fourier series of function $f(x) = \cos(3x)$ on $(-\pi, \pi)$

Comment: $\cos(3x)$ is its own Fourier series.

Comment: Or do you want $f(x) = \frac12 e^{-3xi} + \frac12 e^{3xi}$?